# A good vue grid alternative instead of using vue infinite loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gridview

I'm having trouble with a [vue infinite loader](https://github.com/PeachScript/vue-infinite-loading) and and/or the data table v-data-table that is used to display the data. The infinite loader component or the v-data-table it's using to display the data is blowing up my memory, even with small amount of data (ex. 50 rows).

I need to find an alternative to display a large number of rows (80K), on a single page without blowing out my memory usage in Chrome/IE.

Is there a good alternative to an infinite loader for what I need? ex. grid view

Will [vuejs-data-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-vuejs-data-grid/) work for loading and displaying a large number of rows ~80K quickly and without using that much memory?

Ideally I'd like to have a scrollable table on the page that has all the data in it.

Answer (score 1):

We recently implemented ag-Grid in a product for showing large amounts of data.

You can see a demo with 100000 rows [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/performance/1).

They also touch on the subject regarding [memory footprint and some examples of how to avoid it](https://www.ag-grid.com/vuex-data-flow/).

Comment: hi.Can you point me to any other examples where object freeze is being used on arrays with vue and vuex? I'm new to both and trying to understand whats going on and how I can reduce the memory footprint for the v-data-table's that are eating all my memory